# How long do users stay logged in if they DON'T check remember me?

Tags: login, core, logout

As the title states, I'm wondering how long users stay logged in if they don't check the "Remember Me" option. I've heard that if they DO check it, it keeps them logged in for 14 days.

But what if they don't? I've tried closing my browser and opening it back up, but the user stays logged in...so it doesn't seem like it's soley a session thing.

Comment: Usually closing the browser should kill it. Are you sure you're browser is clearing sessions? On Firefox e.g. you can tell him to keep sessions states.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Take a look at the source:](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L842)

```
832         if ( $remember ) {
833                 /**
834                  * Filter the duration of the authentication cookie expiration period.
835                  *
836                  * @since 2.8.0
837                  *
838                  * @param int  $length   Duration of the expiration period in seconds.
839                  * @param int  $user_id  User ID.
840                  * @param bool $remember Whether to remember the user login. Default false.
841                  */
842                 $expiration = time() + apply_filters( 'auth_cookie_expiration', 14 * DAY_IN_SECONDS, $user_id, $remember );
843 
844                 /*
845                  * Ensure the browser will continue to send the cookie after the expiration time is reached.
846                  * Needed for the login grace period in wp_validate_auth_cookie().
847                  */
848                 $expire = $expiration + ( 12 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS );
849         } else {
850                 /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/pluggable.php */
851                 $expiration = time() + apply_filters( 'auth_cookie_expiration', 2 * DAY_IN_SECONDS, $user_id, $remember );
852                 $expire = 0;
853         }
```

Ir "remember" is checked you have `14 * DAY_IN_SECONDS`, line 842. If not, you have `2 * DAY_IN_SECONDS`, line 851.

Note that that function is pluggable and the `auth_cookie_expiration` filter can be used to alter both values.

Comment: Ha! Just copied form Trac, @Pete :)